# ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined) rails App on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, production-environment, webpacker

I have an exact same code deployed on heroku app. I update the **heroku stack to 18** but now as the build is required before the new stack to take place I am getting the below error.
I tried all different scenarios including force push **git push heroku master:main -f** but nothing seems to be working.

here are the error logs that comes just before build is about to complete.

> remote: -----> nginx-buildpack app detected
>
> remote: cp: cannot stat 'bin/nginx-heroku-18': No such file or
> directory
>
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile nginx-buildpack app.
>
> remote:
>
> remote:  !     Push failed
>
> remote: Verifying deploy...
>
> remote:
>
> remote: ! Push rejected to my-app-prod.
>
> remote:
>
> To https://git.heroku.com/my-app-prod.git
>
> ! [remote rejected]   HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook
> declined)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to
> 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app-prod.git'

Comment: It means: *read the previous messages to see why heroku thinks there is something wrong with your code.* Note in particular: `remote: cp: cannot stat 'bin/nginx-heroku-18': No such file or directory` and `remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile nginx-buildpack app.`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and answering my own question in case it might save someone's time.

Actually, there were multiple NGINX buildpacks in my Heroku app and they were causing issues while updating to Heroku stack-18. In my case, removing one of the **nginx-buildpack** solved my issue.